# more efficient way to get proportion of ones using groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

i1 = ["AA", "AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "BB"]
i2 = ["B1", "B1", "B1", "A1", "A1", "A1"]
col1 = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
col2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
col3 = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

df = pd.DataFrame({"I1": i1,
                  "I2": i2,
                  "Col_1":col1,
                  "Col_2":col2,
                  "Col_3":col3})
```

What I would like to do is to get the the proportion of 1s (ones) for each i1 and i2 for each column. For example the value for `I1=AA` and `I2=B1` should be `Col_1=1,Col_2=0, Col_3=0.66`.

I am getting the required output using the following code:

```
df.groupby(["I1", "I2"])[["Col_1", "Col_2", "Col_3"]].sum()/df.groupby(["I1", "I2"])[["Col_1", "Col_2", "Col_3"]].count()
```

However I don't think this is the best way to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mean` if there are only `1` and `0` values, because `mean` by defintion is `sum / count`:

```
#mean of all numeric columns (without I1, I2)
df1 = df.groupby(["I1", "I2"]).mean()
#if need specify columns names
#df1 = df.groupby(["I1", "I2"])["Col_1", "Col_2", "Col_3"].mean()
print (df1)
          Col_1     Col_2     Col_3
I1 I2                              
AA B1  1.000000  0.000000  0.666667
BB A1  0.333333  0.666667  0.000000
```